Common reporting standard
I have a question that I still have no answer for.
I know that countries have a mutual agreement called Common Reporting Standard which is thought for fiscal transparency, but how does it operate?
If a citizen of A open a bank account in B with the B-issued TIN, will the account information stay in B, or is it going to be transferred to A as well? In other words, does it operate based on nationality or based on a certain country issued TIN number?
For example, I'm an Italian national in Belgium, and I have a Belgian TIN. I opened a bank account here in Belgium, so does all my information stay in Belgium or does that go to Italy as well??? Thanks for the answers.

Background re Common Reporting Standard https://www.crs.hsbc.com/en/frequently-asked-questions also TIN is presumably being used as an acronym for "Taxpayer Identification Number"

It goes to the signatory countries you are a tax resident of
Your tax residency is self-reported under the due diligence procedures of, in your case, Belgium. The fact that you used an Italian ID to open the account would trigger the process. Plus your innate sense of honesty, of course. Once you have been issued a TIN, it’s worldwide forever.
If you reported that you were a tax resident of Italy, Belgium will send your information to Italy once a year. If you cease being a tax resident of Italy, you need to tell the Belgian authorities and they’ll stop.
